# how to create swagger json routes using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, swagger-2.0

I want to create this type of JSON using swagger in laravel, how is it possible?

```
"parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CustomerAuthenticateResponse"
            }
          }
        ],
```

How this create this route: **#/definitions/CustomerAuthenticateResponse** ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution to pass body request(json) using swagger.

**Controller:**

```
class abcController extends Controller
{
    /*
     * @SWG\Post(
     *      path="/api/user",
     *       tags={"User"},
     *      operationId="ApiV1saveUser",
     *      summary="Add User",
     *      consumes={"application/json"},
     *      produces={"application/json"},
     *      @SWG\Parameter(
     *          name="body",
     *          in="body",
     *          @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/User"), //User Model
     *      ),
     *      @SWG\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="Success"
     *      ),
     * )
     */
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
     }
}
```

**User Model:**

```
/**
    * @SWG\Definition(
    *      required={"name","email"},
    *      type="object",
    *      @SWG\Xml(name="User")
    * ),
    * @SWG\Property(format="byte", type="string", property="name", description="User Name"),
    * @SWG\Property(format="byte", type="string",property="email", description="Email")
    */
    class User extends Model
    {
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/darkaonline/l5-swagger)
After installing you can put the definitions in the phpdoc of your controller.

```
class PetController
{
    /**
     * @OAS\Post(
     *     path="/pet",
     *     tags={"pet"},
     *     summary="Add a new pet to the store",
     *     operationId="addPet",
     *     @OAS\Response(
     *         response=405,
     *         description="Invalid input"
     *     ),
     *     security={
     *         {"petstore_auth": {"write:pets", "read:pets"}}
     *     },
     *     requestBody={"$ref": "#/components/requestBodies/Pet"}
     * )
     */
    public function addPet()
    {
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/3.x/Examples/petstore-3.0/controllers/Pet.php)

Comment: Thanks, but I got the actual solution to it.